# Change all "px" values to "vw" on large window sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change all `px` values (for example `padding`, `margin`, and `font-size`) to `vw` values with a `calc(value / 0.2)` function.

How is it possible to do that?

```js
window.onresize = Resize;
window.onload = Resize;

function Resize(){
    let mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 2000px)");

    if (mq.matches) {
        // all "px" values should change to "vw" values, with a "calc(... / 0.2)" to keep it in normal sizes
    }
    else{
        // take previous pixel values
    }
}
```

```css
div {
font-size: 30px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Thaaaanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very strange approach to solving this problem.
Changing css trough javascript is a very hard operation - after each changing browser will redraw your html page. 
Why you don't want to use css with media query?

```
@media (min-width: 2000px) {
/*your vw sizes*/
}
```

Comment: Ok, but with your approach you will lose all you users because of very slow page display.
If you still  want do this - you can use this code

[code]`let all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (let i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     let style = window.getComputedStyle(all[i]),
          font_size =parseFloat( style.getPropertyValue('font-size') );
    all[i].style.fontSize = (font_size * 0.2) + 'px';
}`[/code]

And than with all other properties.

But I highly not recommend do this on your project!!!